# NHibernate Leaking Connections/Transactions

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net, structuremap

We have NHibernate 3.1 setup using Fluent NHibernate and our session's life is managed using StructureMap 2.6.1. This is within a Web Application using VB.NET (some projects are in C#).

We're getting exceptions from production that makes it sound like multiple threads are attempting to use the same connection/transaction. These only happen when connection pooling is turned on. Turning connection pooling off clears these exceptions up, but we're seeing significant performance issues, so it's a temporary fix.

When calling session.BeginTransaction()

> The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:970000004d.
>   The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session.

When calling transaction.Rollback()

> Transaction not connected, or was disconnected

When attempting to inject ISession through StructureMap. (This only seems to happen occasionally when connection pooling is turned off.)

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Our NHibernateRegistry for SturctureMap looks like this:

```
var dbConfiguration = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ModuleConfig.GetSettings().NHibernateConnectionString)
     .AdoNetBatchSize(100).IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(dbConfiguration)
    .Mappings(m =>
    {
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MapMarker>();
        m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<EntityMarker>()
            .Where(x => 
                x.GetInterface(typeof(ISubClassEntity).Name) == null && 
                x.GetInterface(typeof(IFakeEntity).Name) == null && 
                typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<ConventionsMarker>()
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<OverridesMarker>()
            .OverrideAll(map => map.IgnoreProperties(x => !x.CanWrite && !x.Name.EndsWith("Id") && !x.PropertyType.IsEnumerable())));
    })
    .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().ProviderClass(typeof(DotNetCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName));

cfg.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
{
    // custom tuplizers here, removed from snippet.
    x.SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "50");
});

var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(sessionFactory);
For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(cx =>
{
    var session = cx.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession();
    session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
    session.SetBatchSize(50);
    return session;
});
```

At the end of each request, we clean up StructureMap with the following call in the Global.asax:

```
Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Make sure we dipose of all http scoped objects
    ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()
End Sub
```

We have a method that we pass a Func to in order to handle our transactions. This is what that code looks like:

```
protected virtual TResult Transact<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
{
    if (!session.Transaction.IsActive)
    {
        TResult result;
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                result = func.Invoke();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Make sure the transaction is still active...
                if(session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException("There was an error while executing within an NHibernate Transaction.", ex);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    return func.Invoke();
}
```

In order to prevent using implicit transactions, we use this Transact method for SELECT statements. Calls to this method look like this (the session is injected via StructureMap using constructor injection):

```
public T Get(TId id)
{
    return Transact(() => session.Get<T>(id));
}
```

My question is, how do we stop connections from being shared between multiple threads, causing the exceptions above? If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your session management. Each thread should have its own session. The session object is not thread save.

Comment: Shouldn't setting the scoping of the ISession variable in StructureMap to HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped ensure I have a separate session per thread/http request?

Comment: If you are in a WCF environment (access by WCF calls) there is no http context and threads are re-used over multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's your problem, but your `Transact()` method seems weird. `session.Transaction` returns a new transaction if there isn't one currently. So your `session.BeginTransaction()` does only start the transaction, but doesn't create it. Objects used in a `using` should also be instantiated there and not before.

Comment: Looking through the NHibernate source, it looks like `session.BeginTransaction()` calls the same property as `session.Transaction` So the Transaction should be created either way. BeginTransaction just calls `Begin()` on the transaction, after it gets created.